# Eigenvalues of the differential operator $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + k\left( \frac{x}{a} - \frac{a}{x}\right)^2$ on $(0,\infty)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sturm-liouville

I'm trying to solve for the eigenvalues of the differential operator $$-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + k\left( \frac{x}{a} - \frac{a}{x}\right)^2$$ over square-integrable functions on $(0,\infty)$ where $k,a$ are positive real constants. In other words, is there a simple solution to the differential equation $$-\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + k\left( \frac{x}{a} - \frac{a}{x}\right)^2 y = \lambda y$$ with $y(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} y(x) = 0$, and if not, is there a way to determine the set of eigenvalues $\{\lambda\}$ ?

Comment: I'm going to go with no. Even when $k = a = 1$ I get a super ugly expression in mathematica involving hypergeometric functions

Comment: Specifically, $y(x)$ equals $$\frac{2^{\frac{1}{4}
   \left(\sqrt{4 a^2 k+1}+2\right)}
   e^{-\frac{\sqrt{k} x^2}{2 a}}
   \left(x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{4 a^2
   k+1}+2\right)} \left(c_1 U\left(\frac{-2 a
   k+\left(\sqrt{4 k a^2+1}+2\right) \sqrt{k}-a
   \lambda }{4 \sqrt{k}},\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{4
   k a^2+1}+2\right),\frac{\sqrt{k}
   x^2}{a}\right)+c_2 L_{\frac{2 a k-\left(\sqrt{4
   k a^2+1}+2\right) \sqrt{k}+a \lambda }{4
   \sqrt{k}}}^{\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 k
   a^2+1}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{k}
   x^2}{a}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: Looks like a Schrödinger equation. Try to separate the $x\to\infty$ solution. You will get the Solutions of the [Quantum harminic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator) $\psi_n$. Then you may try the Ansatz $ f_{n,m} =\psi_n\sum_{0\leq i \leq m }x^i a_i$.

Comment: Also, if $ka = l(l+1)$ for some $l \in \mathbb{N}$ this is just the (i think) 3-d Harmonic Oscillator, which is also easily solved, since all degrees of freedom separate.